# Placing *both* string and image on pasteboard

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to put *both* a string and an image onto the pasteboard. If I use

```
let str : String
let img : UIImage

// ...

UIPasteboard.general.items = [ [ String ( kUTTypeText  ) : str ],
                               [ String ( kUTTypeImage ) : img ] ]
```

the image pastes fine but not the string. The string is in this weird encoded form.

I've tried different types as well as converting the string to `NSString` or `UTF8` but it either crashes with `value for pasteboard type 'public.text' is not a valid property list type` or the string remains in some coded form.

**EDIT**

If I paste it into Notes this is what I see.

[image: Pasted text and image in Notes]

and if I tap on the text it expands into

[image: Pasted text in Notes]

while if I add

```
print ( "Copied \( str )" )
```

I get

```
Copied 960 939 379 918 958 884 971 672 962 127 852 754 715 ...
```

in the console.

Also, if I just do

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = str
```

it works as expected albeit then I only copy a string.

Comment: What does “weird encoded form” mean concretely?

Comment: @MartinR It pastes (in Notes) in something that says ```text 723 bytes``` and if I tap on it I get ```e5472b...``` - not at all the string I was hoping to see.

Comment: @MartinR I've edited to add images to explain.

Comment: Have you tried the kUTTypeUTF8PlainText type?

Comment: @D.Mika Thanks !!!!! I tried quite a few combinations with no luck. However, this works! Not sure how on earth I did not try it earlier. If you post it as answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `kUTTypeUTF8PlainText` as type key.

BR
Dirk